# OCMock version 3 will not recognized class methods

Tags: ios, testing, ocmock

I am trying to use OCMock version 3 on class methods.  These methods are not recognized.  Does anyone know why and how do I solve this.  When I am typing the code for the stub the maskWithObjectType method does not appear.  I enter it anyway and try the test.  Some code is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ObjectMask : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) Class objectType;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray* requestedFields;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary* children;
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) ObjectMask* parent;
#pragma mark - Factory
+(instancetype)maskWithObjectType:(Class)objectType;
```

The mocking is

```
id mockMask = OCMClassMock([ObjectMask class]);
OCMStub([mockMask maskWithObjectType:[someotherclass class]]);
[mockMask maskWithObjectType:[someotherclass class]];
OCMVerify(mockMask);
```

When I run the test I get the error

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[OCMockObject(PGWS3ObjectMask) maskWithObjectType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe420e0ca60"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you got by `OCMClassMock(cls)` is an instance object, not a class, i.e.,

```
id mockMask = OCMClassMock([ObjectMask class]);
```

just returns an instance.

---

If you want to invoke ObjectMask's class method `+maskWithObjectType:`, try

```
id mockMaskForSomeOtherClass = [ObjectMask maskWithObjectType:[someotherclass class]];
```

Comment: So I basically use the normal method to invoke a class method call then do I convert the mockMaskForSomeOtherClass for example to a OCMClassMock object?

Comment: @LorenzHMenke sorry, what do u mean? There's no OCMClassMock object, it's just a macro, which defined as `OCMClassMock(cls) [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:cls]`. u can just use it like `PGWS3ObjectMask * obj = OCMClassMock([PGWS3ObjectMask class]);`.

Comment: OK that is clearer now, some confusion, I am testing it it works.